# Импорт SQL дампа через sqlpus

Tags: база-данных, oracle, dump, sqlplus

Имеется дамп в формате .sql, который необходимо импортировать на сервере. Из инструментов только sqlplus. Проблема в том что sqlplus требует чтобы после каждого CREATE TABLE был / и только после / запускается создание таблицы. А в дампе никаких / нет. Дамп выглядит примерно так:

```
DROP TABLE...;
CREATE TABLE...;
INSERT INTO...;
```

Когда доходит до INSERT-а ничего не вставляется потому что таблица не создана (т.е из-за того что после команды создания таблицы нету /). Править файл возможности нет потому что он огромный (~700 МБ). Как сделать импорт такого файла? Можно ли как-нибудь указать в опциях чтобы таблица создавалась автоматически без необходимости писать / после команды создания?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно написать простую программку, которая будет вставлять "/" после каждой ";" в файл дампа.

Answer (score 3):

Для этого существует переменная `sqlterminator`.

DDL команды без PL/SQL блока (`create table` в том числе) передаются на исполнение сразу после символа определённого в `sqlterminator` и не требуют завершения символом "/" (slash).

Вставка каким либо способом "/" после каждой ";", как это предложено в принятом ответе, приведёт либо к `ORA-00911: invalid character`, либо все команды выполнятся дважды. Не лишена смысла идея заменить ";" на "/" и установить `sqlterminator` на символ "/" по умолчанию.

Проверьте:

```
SQL> show sqlterminator
sqlterminator ";" (hex 3b)

create table t1 (id number);

Table created.

insert into t1 values (1);

1 row created.

drop table t1;

Table dropped.
```

Установить так:

```
SQL> set sqlterminator ";"
```