# DDL команда после ввода не выполняется и ожидает дополнительных действий

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

[image: img 1]

От меня требуется еще какое-то действие и я не могу понять какое.

Comment: добавьте `/` (slash) в конце (в 6 строке) `CREATE ...` блока

Comment: и между `begin` и `end` что-то должно быть. Хотя бы `null;`

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо.

Comment: Странно, и репутация >10, и не первый день на этом ресурсе, и такой низкокачественный вопрос.

Comment: @0xdb потому, что часто самые банальные вещи нигде не расписаны и не понятно, как их загуглить. Помню, когда первый раз знакомился с sqlplus тоже долго залипал, почему мои скрипты выполняются не до конца )

Comment: Просто интересно, с какими ключевыми словами вы искали?

Comment: @0xdb я не помню уже, года 4 прошло :) В конечном счете я разобрался без помощи СО )

Comment: @Viktorov Вы скорее всего правы. Я просто помнил, что подобное было, но через поиск здесь на SO свой собственный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/157248/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82-sql-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-sqlpus/757518?s=3|16.0093#757518) не нашёл, хотя и старался. Есть ешё над чем поработать.

Comment: @Viktorov Да, на ruSO действительно нет прямого ответа на - "зачем нужен слэш после комманд содержащих plsql блок?". Если у вас есть время/желание , то замените заголовок и дайте  ответ. Пример [есть](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079949/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-semicolon-vs-a-slash-in-oracle-sql) (лучшие ответы - не принатые).

Comment: @0xdb вопрос не в том, зачем нужен слэш. Если вы можете его задать, гугл уже даст вам ответ. Вопрос именно в том, а что вообще нужно и чего не хватает? И вот как это задавать в гугл не всегда понятно)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Команда выполняется немедленно после после символа определённого в `sqlterminator` (по умолчанию ";" - *semicolon*), если она не может содержать PL/SQL блока. Например:

```
create table ... ;
create view ... ;
create type ... is table of ... ;
```

Команды, которые содержат PL/SQL блок или потенциально могущие его содержать, а также анонимные блоки, требуют для выполнения символ "/" - *slash*.

> SQL*Plus stores the subprograms you enter in the SQL buffer. Execute the current subprogram with a RUN or slash (/) command. A semicolon (;) is treated as part of the PL/SQL subprogram and will not execute the command.

В PL/SQL блоке символ ";" является частью синтаксиса, а не символом, который завершит запись в буффер и выполнит команду.

Например, следуюшие команды не будут выполнены после завершения символом ";":

```
create trigger ... ;
/ 
create type ... as object (...); 
/
<<anonymous>> declare ... begin ...  end anonymous;   
/
```

Comment: я бы еще добавил "классику" в качестве примера - анонимный PL/SQL block - `begin ... end; /` ;-)

Comment: @MaxU Точно, упомянул, а в примере не показал. Спасибо за замечание.